# how read and write one file at once by using thread

Tags: python-3.x

I have N-file to open and I want obtain N-new file. I want process ONE file at time by using thread to prevent the GUI tkinter freezing. In real case to process a file I need to wait about 1-2 minute.

```
open file1-->read-->create new file1-->close file  
open file2-->read-->create new file2-->close file  
open file3-->read-->create new file3-->close file
```

In the test code below, there aren't open file in reading and writing mode, I use a simple list. In the while loop if the count is a big number I did not have the right result:

```
#I expect an output like:   
#100000000 file1 test release  
#100000000 file2 test release  
#100000000 file3 test release
#Indeed I obtain strange result like file3 as first result not in third position

from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import threading, time

def th(lol):
         global mythread, lock
         mythread = threading.Thread(target=aprifil2, args=(lol,))
         mythread.start()

def aprifil2(lol):
               global lock, m
               lock.acquire()
               try:
                   s=0
                   while(s<100000000):
                       s+=1
                   print(s, i)
                   scr()
               finally:
                      print('release\n')
                      try:
                          lock.release()
                      except RuntimeError:
                                          print('end')

def scr():
          print('test\n')

def ok():
          global lock, i
          lock = threading.Lock()
          m=['file1','file2', 'file3']
          for i in m:
                     lol=i
                     th(lol)
                     time.sleep(1)

finestra= Tk()
button_cerca = ttk.Button(finestra, text = "avvia", command = ok)
button_cerca.pack()
button_a = Entry(finestra)
button_a.pack()
```

Comment: you mean you want the 3 files be processed sequentially? in that case you have to create 1 thread and process the 3 files in it, not 3 threads.

Comment: yes, sequentially. One thread is enoght but I need that the tkinter GUI not freeze...anyway I don't understand where I mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from datetime import datetime as dt
import threading, time


def th():
         global mythread, cro
         mythread = threading.Thread(target=ok)
         cro = threading.Thread(target=cronou)
         mythread.start()

def aprifil2(z):
                      global m, state_crono, zero
                      s=0
                      while(s<10000000):
                              s+=1
                      print(s, z)
                      scr()
                      print(crono.get())
                      print('\n')
                      zero = dt.now()-dt.now()
                      if(z==m[len(m)-1]):
                                         state_crono = False
                                         time.sleep(0.01)
                                         crono.set('')

def scr():
          print('test\n')

def ok():
          global i, m, state_crono
          state_crono = True
          cro.start()
          m=['file1','file2', 'file3']
          for z in m:
                     aprifil2(z)

def cronou():
            global zero
            zero = dt.now()-dt.now()
            while(state_crono == True):
                                       ti = dt.now()
                                       time.sleep(0.01)
                                       tf = dt.now()
                                       zero += tf-ti
                                       crono.set(str(zero)[0:10])

finestra= Tk()
button_cerca = ttk.Button(finestra, text = "avvia", command = th)
button_cerca.pack()
button_a = Entry(finestra)
button_a.pack()
crono = StringVar()
tex_cronometro = Label(finestra, textvariable=crono, font=("Helvetica",11,"bold"))
tex_cronometro.pack()
finestra.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code is hard to understand, and probably won't be helpful to others. It would be good to add an explanation. For example, what's the point of the `while(s<10000000)` loop? It would also help if you used meaningful variable names -- `z` and `m` give no hint as to what they represent.

Comment: The while loop represent the writing process (new file). "z" represent each file that must be open in sequentially. So I open one file (like z[0], z[1] etc etc....) and writing.